How to stop bevel modifier weight without duplicated vertices?
I'm using the bevel modifier with the weight limit method in order to have more control about which edge will have bevels, but it has an influence on the connected edges that sometimes I want a hard curve.

The technique I learned is to duplicate those vertices I want to break the bevel because it would generate a zero length edge between them, and that edge will have bevel weight zero.
The problem is if I merge vertices by distance I'd lose that configuration, it requires me to pay attention to always unselect those vertices when I'm doing the merge.
I know I could slightly shift the duplicated vertices in order to not be in the exact same position, but I don't want to corrupt my mesh with imprecisions.
I wonder if the bevel modifier doesn't have some settings at vertex level that would control which direction it's allowed to expand. Or if there is a different technique that would allow me to have fine grained control over bevels.

There is no other way. The particular result you are looking for with bevel modifier requires that particular kind of topology.
You could give the vertices some attribute and make yourself a geometry nodes tool to quickly deselect them.
Use Add Attribute and Set Attribute:

Set Attribute requires the attribute you want to set to be selected:

Geometry node tool:

Then you can access it from the menu:

You can also make a hot-key or add it to Quick Favorites menu.
You could also just make a tool that merges by distance ignoring vertices with that attribute:


Now that you mentioned it, I could also use vertex groups. But I hope blender developers could think about a better solution for that.
